# How to make photos properly sized in img tag to fit proportional to the screen?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have this photo page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_image.php?hike_photo_id=106&photo_path=http://www.comehike.com/img/hiking_photos/-1_311_5/full_IMG_4612.jpg

As you can see, the picture is waaaaay  bigger that the screen.  Is there a way to downsize the photos to keep its proportions of length and width, but also to fit nicely on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `width:100%` to its style.

---

```
<img src="http://www.comehike.com/img/hiking_photos/-1_311_5/full_IMG_4612.jpg" style="border: none; width: 100%;" alt="California Nature" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
width: 100%;
```

That will keep it proportional and size it to the width of its container.

Comment: Thanks - is the right way to put the styling in the img tag, or the surrounding <p> tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding like `width="800"` to the the `<img>` tag. However, this is the "ugly" fix. It's much better to use some photo editing program to just resize the actual image to a suitable width instead. This saves bandwidth and makes the user experience much better.

Answer (score 1):

give your image container a percentage width, that way when the screen is resizing or the user is looking at smaller monitor the container will adjust. next to keep the image width/height ratio correct use below css on image tag.

```
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
```

Comment: Try adding more detail to your answer to explain how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add **width** as a percentage value as it will help you with all resolutions, **max-width**, and **min-width** can help you with maintaining the size of the picture going too small on mobiles or going too big on the desktop.

```
img{
width: 50%;
max-width: 300px;
min-width: 175px;
}
```

```
<img src="http://www.comehike.com/img/hiking_photos/-1_311_5/full_IMG_4612.jpg" alt="">
```